# How to get text of xml tag using js?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

```
<newsitem itemnum="1"> 
    <newsdate>6.18.3425</newsdate> 
    <title>End Of The Line For The Incumbent?</title> 
    <body> 
        The Universal News Network is reporting that <person>His 
        Magnificence The Supreme Leader For Life</person> 
        announced today that he has decided not to be cloned for 
        a 14th term. 
    </body>
</newsitem>
```

So, in this, I have to get all text inside body tag using js in HTML. I am able to get "The Universal News Network is reporting that" part and then added "His Magnificence The Supreme Leader For Life" by getting person tag using `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('person')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`.

I need to get that data in a loop and then show this in a table and next `<body>` has different child tag called `<program>` occurring more than one time in the same tag.

Comment: could you please tell how it should look and any code snippet that you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this, ntxt += <"td>"+nBody[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+nPerson[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Comment: Bouncing down the XML into a DOM tree structure using the browser yields some interesting results. It basically ignores the `<body>` tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entirety of your attempt. What you've shown in that comment is not a loop. Also, you'll likely want to look into the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of the `body` node.

Comment: I have created code pen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oqLePG?editors=1010 , not sure if you are trying to display body and person in table??

Comment: Thank you @NagaSaiA, I got it.

Comment: Did my code in code pen worked for you :)